# The function of "but" as a preposition

Tags: grammar, prepositions, gerunds, parts-of-speech

Is the function of "but" in the sentences below a preposition, please?
If so, what's the exact rule on the case? That is, what part of speech is used after it, *a bare infinitive*, a *full-infinitive*, *an adjective*, *a noun* or what?

*We've had nothing **but trouble** with this car.*
*The problem is anything **but easy**.*
*I don't intend to do anything **but to wait** for news.*
*He does nothing **but eat**.*

Comment: Fine. A couple of online resources take the preposition form of *but* into account, but what will we have afterwards? Is it just like the rest of the prepositions, that is, the word after it should be a *noun (phrase), gerund-participle, object* form?

Comment: It has the same meaning as if you replaced it with *except for*

Comment: @Sean, but I don't think you can replace it with _except for_ in every case. In particular, I don't find _The problem is anything except for easy_ works. (_Anything except easy_ is better, but I'm still not sure about it).

Comment: The issue is really both complicated and controversial.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a preposition: I think it is a sort of coordinating conjunction. The structure "anything/nothing but X" can play various roles - noun phrase, adjective phrase, adverbial phrase, verb phrase, and X plays that same role.

So in your examples:

> nothing but trouble - NP
>
> anything but easy - AP
>
> do anything but to wait - VP
>
> does nothing but eat - VP

To my ear, the VP form requires the infinitive without "to", unless it the phrase is introduced by a verb which requires "to", in which case it is optional. So

> He eats -> he does nothing but eat

but

> I don't intend to wait -> I don't intend to do anything but wait **or** I don't intend to do anything but to wait.

_

Comment: Thanks +1. I, too, think **but** can't take the preposition form without complying with the rules related to "Prepositions + N/NP/Gerund-participle, Object".

Comment: I don’t want to argue; you’ve taught me a lot over the years. But based on what I read in the dictionary, I thought this mapped pretty closely with the prepositional meaning (**but** `prep.` - except : _we were [never anything but poor](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/but); there’s been [nothing but trouble](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/but_1) since he left; I trusted [no one but him](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/but); he spoke [nothing but Greek](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/but)_). Is this a gray area?

Comment: I don't know, @J.R. It is the same sense as that, but a far as I know prepositions introduce noun phrases and not any other kind of structure. I suspect that _anything/nothing but_ is _sui generis_.

Comment: There're, of course, some resources like [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/linking-words-and-expressions/but), [bbc.co.uk](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv161.shtml), that treat **but** just like any other preposition.

Comment: Some other resources like [britishcouncil](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/verbs-prepositions), and [academicguides](https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/prepositions) and [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/English_in_Use/Prepositions,_Conjunctions,_and_Interjections) that even don't take **but** as part of prepositions.

Comment: @Abbasi - I don't think those British Council and Academic Guides links are meant to be _exhaustive_ lists of prepositions. The absence of a particular word there doesn't say much about that word.